# Как подключить llvm к проекту visual studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, llvm

Выходят ошибки вроде "class "llvm::Attribute" не содержит члена "ArgMemOnly", "не удаётся открыть источник файл llvm/IR/Intrinsics.gen" и похожие.
Помогите пожалуйста. Возможно это глупый вопрос, но как правильно подключить библиотеку LLVM к проекту c++ в Visual studio? Хорошего объяснения на русском языке я найти не могу.
Скачал исходники, и что с ними дальше делать?
Если просто файлы подключить к проекту, то выходят ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LLVM это набор библиотек, а не одна, поэтому добавлять их к своему проекту довольно муторно, но можно:

[Здесь](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#usage) есть пример того, как с помощью cmake сгенерировать из исходников .sln с библиотеками. В простейшем случае это команда:

`$ cmake -G "Visual Studio 15" path/to/llvm/source/root` (путь к корневой директории с исходниками). Вызывается из билд директории - той, в которой будут результаты строительства.

Может быть полезна опция `-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86"` (чтобы строить только для одной архитектуры, например x86).

Дальше добавляете каждый проект в свой солюшн (Solution Explorer -> Add -> Existing project).

Но мне было удобнее делать по-другому - в сгенерированном .sln создавать свой проект/проекты (в отдельном фильтре).

И, конечно, в обоих случаях нужно указать зависимые библиотеки в настройках линкера.

Comment: Да, я видел эту страницу. Но проблема в том, что я не могу понять,что там написано, так как она целиком на английском.

Comment: Ответ отредактирован, добавлен пример вызова cmake для генерации.